# How do I change the value of a variable, and then print the new value?

Tags: python, variables

I am a bit of an intermediate coder and am learning in my own time (and in classes) and am confused. I wanted to change a value of a variable, then print that new value, but I can't see how to do it. Can I please be told how to update a variable's value? Thanks!

```
#Variables

randomNum = random.randint(1, 50)

currentNum = 100

#Code
def program():

  option = input("The current value is " + str(currentNum) + ". Would you like to 
raise it (y) or lower it (n)?")

  if option == "y":

    print(currentNum + randomNum)
    program()

  elif option == "n":

    print(currentNum - randomNum)
    program()
  else:
    print("Input a valid option.")
    program()
program()
```

Comment: You seem to be creating a recursive function but don't pass the variables with the call. If you don't want that, then you should at least set currentNum in your program function , something like: currentNum += randomNum.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing currentNum when calling for example print(currentNum + 1). This will translate to print(100 + 1), which it will do, but it will not change currentNum. Do this instead:

```
currentNum = currentNum + randomNum
print(currentNum)
```

Also, I'm not sure if you need to do this, but try adding

```
def program():
    global currentNum
    global randomNum
    ...
```

if there are issues later.

Furthermore, randomNum will always be the same value, because it is only calculated once, when the program runs through the line in which randomNum is initialised. If you want randomNum to be a new random number each time the user enters 'y' or 'n', you have to define it within the function, so that it is calculated anew every time program is called.

```
def program():
    global currentNum
    randomNum = random.randint(1, 50)
    ...
```